# MathLink: How to change the default listening IP address?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, remote-access, internet

I have multiple VPNs, one gives local IP address 10.8.0.6 and another is 10.2.3.2. Now I wish to access machines in 10.2.3.x but Mathematica listens in 10.8.0.6 which is not known for those machines. So I wonder if there's a way to change the default listening up of Mathematica.

For example, if I run

```
LinkCreate[LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]
```

I get

```
LinkObject["35609@10.8.0.6,34271@10.8.0.6",700,12]
```

But what I actually want is

```
LinkObject["35609@10.2.3.2,34271@10.2.3.2",700,12]
```

I understand this might not be a Mathematica problem but maybe there's a way inside Mathematica. Or maybe I just need to work with my IP routes, but some hints will be much appreciated.

**About remote kernels**

Thanks to sakra, I found that by simply add `LinkHost->"host"` in the `List of options for LaunchRemote` area of remote kernels panel, the default host is set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the undocumented `LinkHost` option, e.g.:

```
LinkCreate[LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP", LinkHost -> "127.0.0.1"]
```

yields:

```
LinkObject["62864@127.0.0.1,62865@127.0.0.1",408,12]
```

Comment: Thanks！I guessed this option might exist but it's displayed red, so I assumed it's not there. And with this option appended to `LaunchRemote`, the remote kernels worked fine as well.